# How to convert UriComponentsBuilder to java.net.URI

Tags: java, spring, uri

The documentation for [`UriComponentsBuilder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html) suggest that it is possible, but not straightforward to convert to a `java.net.URI`.

The following seems to work, but involves an intermediate serialization by `toUriString()`.

```java
UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(origin+base);
java.net.URI uri = null;
try {
    uri = new URI(uriBuilder.toUriString());
}
catch (Exception e) {}                                                              // TODO: insanity
String response = restTemplate.getForObject(uri,String.class);
```

The constructor for `java.net.URI` declares a throw:

> java.net.URISyntaxException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Is there a nice way of doing this that doesn't require dealing with exceptions?

*A really helpful answer might provide some insight as to why `build` has different return types depending on the input type.*

Comment: `uriBuilder.build` what is wrong with that.

Comment: @M.Deinum: It's a little muddled by the different possible return values.

Comment: Why? `build` return a `URI`... That is clearly explained in the javadoc you yourself point at... Just pass in en empty map `Collections.emptyMap` .

Comment: @M.Deinum: `Collections.emtpyMap()` may be the answer that I was looking for.  `new Object[0]` also seems to work.  Both approaches are kind of strange to me -- but either looks better than my initial solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A new UriComponentsBuilder class helps to create UriComponents
>   instances by providing fine-grained control over all aspects of
>   preparing a URI including construction, expansion from template
>   variables, and encoding.

The `{type}` bind to queryParam in path.

```
 URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance().scheme("http").host("docuconv.claztec.net")
                .path("/cgi/{type}")
                .queryParam("path", file.getDownloadUrl())
                .queryParam("realname", file.getName())
                .queryParam("servicecode", file.getServiceCode())
                .queryParam("useragent", file.getUserAgent())
                .queryParam("charset", file.getCharset())
                .queryParam("format", file.getOption())
                .build().expand(file.getType())
                .encode()
                .toUri();
```

[UriComponentsBuilder](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-uricomponentsbuilder)

Comment: This contains the secret sauce that I was looking for!  `.build()` returns type [`UriComponents`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponents.html), which has function `toUri()` -- which is what I couldn't find before.